# REST request doesn't work outside of Explorer

Tags: restler, swagger

I'm using Restler's API Explorer (a fork of Swagger UI) and when I test a service call there it works fine but when I cut and paste the same URL into Chrome's Advanced REST Client I get a  "403 Forbidden" error. How can that be? Is there some sort of required header parameter that needs to be passed with the request?

Here are the screen shots:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the content type right. Make sure you are sending the data as JSON (`application/json`)

You need to add a header

```
Content-Type application/json
```